# Notifications doesn't appear when app is destroyed

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I have a notification in my app that works fine when app is running. But when the app is destroyed, notification doesn't appear.I use alarmmanger in that app.What should I do?

Comment: what kind of notification is that? I mean is that push notification or local notifition? And please elaborate more your scenario along with code. This will help us more to resolve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some vendors don't allow apps run in background and change alarm manager behavior. So sometimes your notification will not be shown when your app is in background. This happens for example Xiaomi and Huawei devices and maybe other vendors but i haven't tested on other manufacturers.
As an solution use `alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle() or alarmManager.setAlarmClock()` methods

Comment: Yeah my device is Xiaomi, I will try your solution,thanks.